# AES 128 encryption in Java Decryption in PHP

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, aes

I have been trying to decrypt a string using AES-128 CBC which was originally crypted using JAVA AES encryption. In java PKCS7 padding is used. And I have tried to encrypt and decrypt using similar PHP code. But I am getting different result.

My Java code

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.util.Base64;

/**
 * @author vipin.cb , vipin.cb@experionglobal.com <br>
 *         Sep 27, 2013, 5:18:34 PM <br>
 *         Package:- <b>com.veebow.util</b> <br>
 *         Project:- <b>Veebow</b>
 *         <p>
 */
public class AESCrypt {

    private final Cipher cipher;
    private final SecretKeySpec key;
    private AlgorithmParameterSpec spec;
    public static final String SEED_16_CHARACTER = "U1MjU1M0FDOUZ.Qz";

    public AESCrypt() throws Exception {
        // hash password with SHA-256 and crop the output to 128-bit for key
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(SEED_16_CHARACTER.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        spec = getIV();
    }

    public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV() {
        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
        ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        return ivParameterSpec;
    }

    public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String encryptedText = new String(Base64.encode(encrypted,
                Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");

        return encryptedText;
    }

    public String decrypt(String cryptedText) throws Exception {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(cryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
        String decryptedText = new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");

        return decryptedText;
    }

}
```

And the equivalent PHP code I am using.

```
<?php

class MCrypt {

    private $iv = '0000000000000000'; #Same as in JAVA              
    private $key = 'U1MjU1M0FDOUZ.Qz'; #Same as in JAVA

    function __construct() {
        $this->key = hash('sha256', $this->key, true);
    }

    function encrypt($str) {
        $iv = $this->iv;
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
        $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return base64_encode($encrypted);
    }

    function decrypt($code) {
        $iv = $this->iv;
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', '');
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $str = mdecrypt_generic($td, base64_decode($code));
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('rijndael-128', 'cbc');
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return $str;
        //return $this->strippadding($str);             
    }

    /*
      For PKCS7 padding
     */
    private function addpadding($string, $blocksize = 16) {
        $len = strlen($string);
        $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
        $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        return $string;
    }

    private function strippadding($string) {
        $slast = ord(substr($string, -1));
        $slastc = chr($slast);
        $pcheck = substr($string, -$slast);
        if (preg_match("/$slastc{" . $slast . "}/", $string)) {
            $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - $slast);
            return $string;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

$encryption = new MCrypt();
echo $encryption->encrypt('123456') . "<br/>";
echo $encryption->decrypt('tpyxISJ83dqEs3uw8bN/+w==');
```

In Java
Plain text = 123456
Cipher text = tpyxISJ83dqEs3uw8bN/+w==

In  PHP

Plain text = 123456
Cipher text = IErqfTCktrnmWndOpq3pnQ==

When I tried to decrpt the Java encrypted text "tpyxISJ83dqEs3uw8bN/+w==" using PHP decryption I am getting an empty array if I removed the padding . Without removing the padding I am getting  "::::::::::"

I think there is some mistake with the IV bytes used in PHP and Java
Can anyone help me on this. I have tried many combinations . Still no result. I am very new to Java concepts.

**------Solution-------**

I have modified my php class according to the comments given by owlstead. may be there is a better way. I am posting it here so that someone may find it helpful in future and your comments are welcome for further improvement.

```
<?php

class MCrypt {

    private $hex_iv = '00000000000000000000000000000000'; # converted Java byte code in to HEX and placed it here               
    private $key = 'U1MjU1M0FDOUZ.Qz'; #Same as in JAVA

    function __construct() {
        $this->key = hash('sha256', $this->key, true);
        //echo $this->key.'<br/>';
    }

    function encrypt($str) {       
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $this->hexToStr($this->hex_iv));
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
        $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);        
        return base64_encode($encrypted);
    }

    function decrypt($code) {        
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $this->hexToStr($this->hex_iv));
        $str = mdecrypt_generic($td, base64_decode($code));
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);        
        return $this->strippadding($str);               
    }

    /*
      For PKCS7 padding
     */

    private function addpadding($string, $blocksize = 16) {
        $len = strlen($string);
        $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
        $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        return $string;
    }

    private function strippadding($string) {
        $slast = ord(substr($string, -1));
        $slastc = chr($slast);
        $pcheck = substr($string, -$slast);
        if (preg_match("/$slastc{" . $slast . "}/", $string)) {
            $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - $slast);
            return $string;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2)
    {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
}

$encryption = new MCrypt();
echo $encryption->encrypt('123456') . "<br/>";
echo $encryption->decrypt('tpyxISJ83dqEs3uw8bN/+w==');
```

Comment: THANK YOU.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  fixed a typo in my key and presto magico!

Comment: @ssdscott i am glad it helped you even after posting 2 years back :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your IV is different, a byte with value zero is different from a character `'0'` which would translate into a byte with value `30`  in hexadecimals or 48 in decimals (if you presume ASCII or UTF-8 encoding).

Comment: what should be the IV ..i have given 16 spaces for IV without luck. i tried to convert byte iv to string in java and got empty string with length 16. I tried encrypt in php using it without any luck.

Comment: Compare the bytes values of the IV on both platforms. Remember that input and output of symmetric ciphers is in bytes, and that the order of the bytes has been predefined for ciphers. You should always get the same result irrelevant of the platform. So make sure the values you input into the algorithms is identical on both platforms. The best way to do this is to print out the input values in hexadecimals right before performing the cryptographic operation. Beware of (character-)encoding/decoding issues! If possible, test the input/output of the algorithm itself using identical *byte arrays*.

Comment: thanks very much owlstead.. i followed the steps you mentioned.. thanks for your patience to answer my question and for the comments here...love u.