# Decrypting AES-128 in PHP from data generated in Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes, mcrypt

Using a lot of different examples on Stackoverflow and other sites I've managed to create a working Java class for encrypting and decrypting strings using AES-128. I need to decrypt and encrypt these same strings in PHP as well to allow 2-way communication, but using PHP's mcrypt I get scrambled and broken strings which do not come close to what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's the Java source (which is wrapped in a function):

```
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] keyBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        digest.update(keyBytes);
        keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digest.digest(), 16);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,};
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText));

        return new String(decryptedBytes);
```

For example, this would return `dyHuhcYI3JIQ4BssSyJ3bjE/sQCOH+fWq2EujW579BU=` using the key/password `J@RMZyv7~Dyd`, and can be decrypted to `Dit bericht is versleuteld!` with that same key.

In PHP, I am using a lot less code, and I am not sure where things are going wrong. I am using `V1gbTVCCbQK7cknbbir5Gg==` as the key for decrypting it, which is the base64 encoded version of the `keyBytes` variable above.

```
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, base64_decode("V1gbTVCCbQK7cknbbir5Gg=="), base64_decode("vdyHuhcYI3JIQ4BssSyJ3bjE/sQCOH+fWq2EujW579BU="), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "0000000000000000");
var_dump($decrypted);
```

That produces some broken string, and I'm not sure how to resolve this just yet. I am sure that something's wrong with my PHP implementation since I can encrypt and decrypt it successfully in Java.

Comment: The trick with crypto is that you don't want to get it working, you want it to be secure. The above code or the code in your answer is not secure; it doesn't use the right key derivation and zero IV's should not be used. It's also missing protection against integrity and authenticity and - when used for peer to peer communication - it won't be confidential either.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @zaph Good remark. I will look into those libraries, I indeed shouldn't use this then.

Comment: @Maarten You're right. I'm still experimenting with this since I've not found any concrete examples for my use case, but I'm going to take a look at how various open source projects handle about the same thing I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the IV which I was using was not quite correct. After experimenting with the questions found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196728/aes-128-encryption-in-java-decryption-in-php) answer, I found out that using the following code I can successfully decrypt my messages:

```
function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hex) - 1; $i += 2) {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i] . $hex[$i + 1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, base64_decode($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, hexToStr('00000000000000000000000000000000'));
```

Note that the IV is now using that function instead of the value "0000000000000000".

Comment: Your code is still insecure.  Does this not bother you?

Comment: It does indeed bother me @luke. I'm still thinking about how to make communication between Java and PHP as secure AND simple as possible while using sockets. It needs to be simple for end users as well; generating certificates isn't that straightforward.